# Reading from file and storing into 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have set up 2 2D arrays in my code, one for storing an array of IDs and another for passwords. I am attempting to read from a text file with the format:

```
    ID1 PASSWORD1
    ID2 PASSWORD2
    ID3 PASSWORD3
    ID4 PASSWORD4
    ID5 PASSWORD5
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_RECORDS 100
#define MAX_INPUT 40

void readFile();
void inputInit();
void DBInit();
void init();


FILE *fp;

char **IDArray;
char **passwordArray;

char *IDInput;
char *passInput;

int main(){
    init();
    readFile();

    return 0;
}

void readFile(){
    fp = fopen("Database_Table.txt","r");

    char line[MAX_INPUT];
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("Error in opening file");
    }
    else{
        int i;
        while(!feof(fp)){
            fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp);
            sscanf(line,"%s\t%s",IDInput,passInput);
            IDArray[i] = IDInput;
            passwordArray[i] = passInput;
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void init(){
    DBInit();
    inputInit();

}

void inputInit(){
    IDInput = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_INPUT);
    passInput = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_INPUT);
}

void DBInit(){
    IDArray = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_RECORDS);
    passwordArray = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_RECORDS);

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_RECORDS;i++){
        IDArray[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_INPUT);
        passwordArray[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_INPUT);
    }
}
```

My issue is that, for some reason, I keep getting a segmentation fault when I try to store the IDs and the Passwords. Any help to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no 2D array, nothing which can represent one or point to one in your code. A pointer is not an array!

Answer (score 1):

int i creates an uninitialised wild i. Replace with int i = 0;

Comment: Oh my mistake, thanks. But now whenever it runs and tries to fill the array the new element that is being inputted is now replacing previous entries. This was my original problem not the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using feof. You should never use feof as the exit indicator for a loop. You can take a look a [this link](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-58.html), it explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is in the lines

```
IDArray[i] = IDInput;
passwordArray[i] = passInput;
```

In these lines you assign pointers, nothing else. This means you do not copy the contents into your preallocated array. To do this, you must use `strcpy` or `strncpy`, e.g.

```
strcpy(IDArray[i], IDInput);
strcpy(passwordArray[i], passInput);
```

Your second error is in the loop termination. The array has space for `MAX_RECORDS` elements, but you don't stop at `MAX_RECORDS`. You read until end of file, which might be much later.

And finally, as @Malcolm already pointed out, you missed the initialisation of `i`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped